# Showing this function is differentiable in the origin

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function in the origin so:
>
> $f(t,t) =t^3+t$ and $f(t,-2t)=2t$
>
> Calculate $D_vf(0,0)$
>
> $v=(1,3)$

I have no idea on how to approach this problem.
I know that because f is differentiable we have

$D_vf(0,0)= Df(0,0)v$

So I should be able to determine the partial derivatives. But how can I do it?
I just need a hint to start the problem, thanks

Comment: Does "Calculate $D_vf(0,0)v=(1,3)$" mean that we have to determinate $v=(v_1,v_2)$ such as the equation is satisfied ?

Comment: Oh no, no! Sorry I didn't realize that bit wasn't clear when I was writing it. It just means that the vecto $v$ is $(1,3)$

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a function that verifies the given condition.

It is clear that this function is most likely a polynomial. So i assumed that, $$ f(x,y)=ax^3+by^3+cx^2y+dxy^2+exy+kx+ly+m,\quad a,b,c,d,e,k,l\ \mbox{and}\ m\in\mathbb{R} $$
After verifying the conditions, i find the following function $$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{3}x^2y+\frac{1}{3}xy^2+\frac{4}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}y $$

Now we calculate, $\nabla f(x,y)$,
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(\begin{array}[c]
 \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}[c]
 \ \frac{4}{3}xy+\frac{1}{3}y^2+\frac{4}{3}\\ \frac{2}{3}x^2+\frac{2}{3}xy-\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right)$$ 
Then, $$\nabla f(0,0)=\left(\begin{array}[c]
\ \frac{4}{3}\\ -\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right) $$
And we have $D_vf(0,0)=\nabla f(0,0)\cdot v$, hence
$$ D_vf(0,0)=\left(\begin{array}[c]
\quad \frac{4}{3}\\ -\frac{1}{3}
\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}[c]
\ 1\\ 3
\end{array}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$$

**Remark:**

The function $f$ that i found is not the only one that satisfies the conditions.